# Motion sickness before actual flight, this is hampering my traveling possiblities

Tags: air-travel, health, aircraft

There's this strange thing that has happened to me for a few years.

Every time I'm traveling via an airplane I get motion sickness even before the actual flight, as in even the day before the actual flight. This causes me to vomit and feel very sick until I arrive to my location and can finally relax again. Has anyone experienced something similair and can I please get any tips, it feels like I've tried everything and I love to travel.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess and say that's not motion sickness, but rather anxiety - so you're probably treating the wrong thing ...

Comment: See your MD about that.

Answer (score 4):

You should seek the advice of your doctor; like others I also believe you are actually describing the symptoms of an anxiety attack and trying to treat it as motion sickness may not help.

Consult a doctor and be frank about your issues as anxiety attacks can have severe consequences. A colleague starts to hyperventilate when she gets on a plane (no matter what the plane) and as you can imagine this exacerbates her anxiety.

She consulted a doctor who prescribed some medication to control her reactions but she still felt the anxiousness of the entire situation. Eventually she took some fear of flying classes.

Now, she simply gets a little frightened during turbulence and the situation is a lot better for her.